# operational error when updating sqlite3 record using Tkinter python

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, crud

I'm testing a search and update feature in tkinter using sqlite3 database that has 2 columsn:
index (1,2,3,4...) and
finished(0 / 1)

my code:

```
root = Tk()

con=sqlite3.connect("db1.db")

c = con.cursor()

df = pd.read_sql("select * from mytable", con=con) 

def search_record():
    df_new = df.loc[df ['index'] == int(index.get())]

    if df_new.finished.values[0] == 0:
        finished.config(text = "No", background='red')
    else:
        finished.config(text = "Yes", background='green')


def update_record():

    ind = index.cget('text')

    if finished.cget("text") == "No":
        finished.config(text = "Yes", background='green')

        c.execute("UPDATE mytable SET finished= 1 WHERE index=?" ,(ind))

    else:
        finished.config(text = "No", background='red')
        c.execute("UPDATE mytable SET finished=0 WHERE index=?" ,(ind))

index_l = Label(root, text="Index")
index_l.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20)

index = Entry(root, width=30)
index.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20)


finished_l = Label(root, text="Voted")
finished_l.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20)

finished = Label(root, width=12)
finished.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20)

search_btn =  Button(root, text='Search', command = search_record)
search_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)

change_btn = Button(root, text='Update', command = update_record)
change_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=10, ipadx=100)

root.mainloop()
```

the search feature is working well, but the update feature is not.
I get the following error when clicking update after a valid search:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\newuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\newuser\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5360\1752272787.py", line 25, in update_record
    c.execute("UPDATE mytable SET finished= 1 WHERE index=?" ,(ind))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "index": syntax error
```

Comment: You need to pass a *tuple or list* as the second argument of `c.execute(...)`, but `(ind)` is not a tuple or list.  Use `(ind,)` or `[ind]` instead.

Comment: `index` is a reserved word.